# Thinkster MEAN Stack Tutorial problems with routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I have been following this tutorial on thinkster.io:

https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/

Everything works fine until I get to the section where we setup mongoose, then I start to hit problems.

First of all in the section "Creating Schemas with Mongoose" it says:

"Connect to our local MongoDB instance by adding the following code into our app.js file:"

But this is unclear - what do they mean by "our" app.js file - we no longer have an app.js that we created as we renamed it to angularApp.js - the only app.js file is the one generated by express/npm which is in the /views/ folder and is full of express configurations.  I personally added the code to this file but am unsure if they meant for us to add it to /public/javascripts/angularApp.js

Secondly, in the "Creating our first route" section, the tutorial instructs us to add the code to routes/index.js but again this file is already populated with express routes and the tutorial is unclear as to whether we append this file with the new route for /posts or to remove the existing express route and add the /posts route instead.

Either way, the result is when I attempt to post the first data to mongodb via curl or postman it results in a 404, indicating the route is not working.

Any help appreciated - there is no comment section on the site for asking questions or troubleshooting, so I am hoping stackoverflow can fill in the gaps :)

Comment: Angular is on the client side. Presumably Mongo access is on the *server* side.

Comment: Yes MongoDB is running as a service - not sure what your point was?

Comment: The Angular app js file is the client app. Running on the client. Putting Mongo initialization/schema code in there wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: I didnt add the code to the angular app js file - as I stated in the original post, I added it to the app.js file in the views/ folder.  My point was that the tutorial wasn't clear on this as in the previous section we changed the name of our app.js to angularApp.js and moved it.

Comment: Yes. You also said you didn't know if it was the right thing to do, and I addressed that concern, and explained why. Not sure what your issue is with this.

Comment: Hey @Paladine do you still have pro account on thinkster?

Answer (score 4):

Here's my code: https://github.com/jakblak/thinkster_mean_app

It's more organized then the original and commented.

Comment: that was a lot of help, thank you.  Sorry I can't upvote you yet.

Comment: I am having another problem now.  My comment upvotes are not writing to the database, I am getting a 500 error instead:  
  
TypeError: Cannot read property 'upvote' of undefined
    at D:\www\flapper-news\routes\index.js:75:16  
  
Here is the section from index.js:    
  
    router.put('/posts/:post/comments/:comment/upvote', function (req, res, next) {  
        req.comment.upvote(function (err, comment) {  
            if (err) { return next(err); }  
            res.json(comment);  
        });  
    });

Comment: I updated the files.  Not sure if this will fix your error though.  There was a missing views folder and missing user.js file.

Comment: I notice in your branch you have 2x $scope.incrementUpvotes in your PostsCtrl?  Can you confirm that your comments upvoting registers in mongodb?

Comment: here is my project on Git https://github.com/thinkprivacy/MEAN - I can't see why I am getting the 500 error, my code looks the same as yours

Comment: try working from my updated files.  Download then do: npm install  -  bower install  -  node app

Comment: my latest commit is working, I had simply not added the router.param() for comments